# Please explain me why apple add UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown to UIInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, orientation

Please can anyone explain me why we need UIInterfaceOrientation? 
I have a problem in my code with this. When i simulate my app on simulator i have this orientation (only once). I don't know how to repair it...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Could you provide some code?

Comment: Maybe just because of a good practice, before setting anything else that is a default value

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs from https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown

`UIInterfaceOrientationUnknow` is added on iOS 8. I am not quite sure about the reason. Perhaps it's something related to the screens size? Or I think it's the status during the screen transition.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Will be more careful in the future.